# Location wasn't copied to other sites after pressing "Save and copy changes to all public communities"

Tags: bug, profile-page, location, profile-edit

1. On es SO, I changed the Location to **Ukhta, Russia**

   > [image]
2. Pressed "Save and copy changes to all public communities".
3. On Users page of en SO it shows correctly.

   > [image]
4. But on other sites (e.g. on MSE) it wasn't changed.

   > [image]

Comment: I've had sketchy history with this with my profile picture. Sometimes I'll change my profile picture and tell it to effect every site, and it will still only effect the site I triggered it from. I need to do it several times for it to actually go through. It doesn't seem be be a caching issue since waiting doesn't help.